# Using command line arguments in for loop (bash)

Tags: bash, for-loop, arguments

I'm trying to write a bash script that's supposed to perform reverse DNS lookup on a range of IP addresses. The idea is to provide the network (first 3 octets) as $1, the start of the range to be checked as $2 and the end of said range as $3.

So I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo "[*] Usage: reverselookup.sh [Network (x.x.x)] [start of range (y)]  [end of range (z)]"
    exit 1
fi

for ip in {$2..$3}
do
    host $1.$ip | grep pointer
done
```

Now I thought that this would use the normal sequence operation in bash for loops, like in

```
for i in {2..5}
```

gives you a loop with 2, 3, 4 and 5. However it doesn't work.

If I echo the $ip inside the loop and run it as e.g.

```
reverselookup.sh 192.168.10 21 50
```

it presents me with

> {21..50}

Does anyone know whether it's possible to make this work?
Or do I have to rethink my appraoch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the description of [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) to see why what you type won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `seq` to replace

```
for ip in {$2..$3}
```

Say:

```
for ip in $(seq $2 $3)
```

Comment: The seq command is probably more portable that the c-style loop. The downside is that it will create an extra process, and that the number of iterations are limited by the size of the command buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the info as well as your approach but since the use case here is a maximum of 255 iterations this shouldn't be an issue. Please do correct me if that's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Brace expansion won't work with variables, because it is performed before the variable expansion. You can use a c-style for loop instead:

```
for ((ip=$2; ip<=$3; ip++))
do
    ....
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the seq command (part of coreutils) to generate the list; like so

```
for ip in $(seq $2 $3)
do
    host $1.$ip | grep pointer
done
```